# Create/alter table for each new user/project

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-performance, create-table, alter

I am building a platform with two kinds of users: Users_A create projects with unique virtual coins associated, and Users_B can buy and exchange this coins.

The problem:

- Approach 1: if I use one unique table as a virtual wallet, the User_B ID will be the row, and each column will be each coin. In this way, I have to ALter the table each time a new project is created.
- Approach 2: I create an electronic wallet (table) for every single User_B.

Which one of the two is worse/better in terms of performance?
Is there any other possible approach?

Comment: Edit your question and clarify what you are trying to build and what are the relations. There is definitely a better approach than any of these 2 in which you won't have to create tables/add columns each time, but I have not enough information to help you.

Comment: Could you please specify what more info you need?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear to me what exactly you are trying to model. But any model that requires ALTERing a table because you add new content to the database is flawed.

That sounds like a basic many-to-many relationship to me:

You definitely need a table for the users:

```
create table users 
(
   user_id integer primary key, 
  ... other columns ...
);
```

and one for the different coins:

```
create table coin
(
  coin_id integer primary key, 
  ... other columns ...
);
```

You need a table for the projects. You said "unique virtual coins associated", so I assume one project deals with exactly one type of coins:

```
create table project
(
   project_id     integer primary key, 
   owner_user_id  integer not null references users,
   coin_id        integer not null references coin
   ... other columns 
);
```

I am not sure what exactly you mean with "buy and exchange" coins, but you probably need something like a transfer table:

```
create table coin_transfer
(
   from_user_id   integer not null references users,
   to_user_id     integer not null references users, 
   project_id     integer not null references project,
   transfer_type  text    not null check (transfer_type in ('buy', 'exchange'))
   amount         numeric not null
);
```

You also mention a "wallet" that belongs to a user. You would never create one table for each wallet, instead a table that contains the information which user owns the wallet. Assuming each user would have one wallet for each coin type you'd need something like this:

```
create table wallet
(
  wallet_id      integer primary key, 
  owner_user_id  integer not null references users, 
  coin_id        integer not null references coin,
   ... other columns ...
);
```

---

The above is only a very rough sketch and because there is a lot of information missing from your question.